# Static IP Leases not working in DD-WRT

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, dd-wrt

If I go to Services --> Services --> Static Leases, and enter the MAC address + desired Hostname + desired IP, then save, it seems like everything worked, but after waiting a day the IP address has not changed.

Under Status --> LAN, the "Client Lease Time" is 1 day, so it should've changed by now.  If I manually delete the client lease from that screen, the old IP is reassigned.  And in fact if I manually do

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

DHCP does not give me *any* address, and I need to locally set a static address to connect to my network.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that **special characters are not allowed in the hostname**.

Specifically, `-` and `_` are allowed, but any other characters I've tried (`?`, `&`, `(`, `)`) cause the DHCP server to silently fail.  DD-WRT will allow you to save and give no indication that anything is wrong, but when you attempt to obtain a new lease it will either give you your old one, or fail entirely.

Removing all special characters from all hostnames caused it to immediately work.

Comment: Since I also encountered this issue - I will try your solution. For me it happened when the lease expiry time was set to none ( or "never" )